What if Adam did not eat the fruit, but Eve did?
If Eve had eaten the fruit in the garden of Eden, but Adam had refused the fruit, what would have likely  happened next?

Only Eve would have been judged and sent out of the garden, though what if questions are often off-topic because they attract different opinions

I'm not sure what to do with this question.  On the one hand, it's not really a hermeneutics questions.  That is, "what does this (sentence, word, paragraph, etc) mean?"  However, it's an interesting question in that it could be reworded something along the lines of, "What texts and their meaning can we bring into play to understand how God deals with those, like Eve, whose moral failure is the result of being deceived?"

Thank you very much for your help, Mike! I will word some of my questions this way going forward.
